# Apache tomcat (8.0.36) gzip is not working I have added following code

Tags: apache, tomcat, compression, gzip

I have added the following code in my server.xml and restarted the tomcat in eclipse but gzipping is not working

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8081" 
protocol="HTTP/1.1"disableUploadTimeout="true" 
compression="on" 
compressionMinSize="2048" 
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"  
compressableMimeType="text/html,
text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css,application/json"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from:

```
protocol="HTTP/1.1"disableUploadTimeout="true"
```

to:

```
protocol="HTTP/1.1" disableUploadTimeout="true"
```

(adding a space before `disableUploadTimeout`).

Comment: Its there but it does not appear in the snippet